# How to concatenate two PHP form fields when carrying over?

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP form that requires first & last name fields. However, when I print the form I want to carry them over and concatenate them into a singular name field. What's the best route for doing this?

Here's what I currently have for the carry over

**Form**

```
<div>
    <?php echo $f->formText('Patient first name:', 'patientfname', '', '100px', 50, 'required')?>
     <?php echo $f->formText('Last name:', 'patientlname', '', '100px', 50, 'required')?>
</div>
```

**Form Print View**

```
<div class="input-field col s8">                            
    <div id="patientfname" type="text" class="validate"></div>
    <div id="patientlname" type="text" class="validate"></div>
    <label class="active" for="patientfname">Patient Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make a hidden field named `name` and have JS populate it.. not sure I follow the requirement though. `$_POST['patientfname'] . ' ' . $_POST['patientlname']` seems easy enough to do.

Comment: @user3783243 Using Post doesn't seem to work when I've tried it. It just pulls in blank fields in the printview page that I have. If I carry them over the way I have it in the Form Print View, the name fields show fine. Doing anything else seems to bring empty strings

Comment: try adding name to form.

Comment: The patientfname and patientlname are in the name arguments

Comment: Maybe you are submitting over `GET`? You dont show form here so `POST` is a guess. If you are submitting over `GET` please reconsider, patient data should be transmitted in a secure manner.

Comment: The form itself is a number of free text fields that you save as you go(the first code). There is a "print" button that takes you to a different page with a different layout that's easier for printers (that's the second code). What else would you need to see?